# Use brackets in a Laravel's directivе

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to add a closing/opening bracket in a Laravel's directive, but PhpStorm shows an error here :(

Laravel says: `ErrorException Undefined property: Illuminate\View\Factory::$startSection` or `ParseError syntax error, unexpected '?'`

Code line: `@section('error-message', 'Oops :(')`

[image]

What should I do? Thanks :)

Comment: I think it's a bug. Tried to replicate it and noticed that if you remove the last `(` (from the face) the warning disappear.

Comment: is it just phpstorm complaining? or does the blade view not get compiled when you try to view it?

Comment: Laravel says: ParseError syntax error, unexpected '?'. Well, it's a Laravel's bug :(

Comment: Interesting. I didn't go that far. Maybe the thing is at the PHP level. But if this is the expected behavior, you could try to make use of a function to scape the parentheses (?)

Comment: I've reported about it in Laravel Bug Tracker. I have been using Laravel for 2 months, but I have already found a bug :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally this kind of thing isn't possible because of the limitations of Blade parsing using regular expressions. I suggest just using a normal section input:

```
@section('error-title')
Not found :(
@endsection
```